# Is -[UITableView reloadData] asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When you call `-reloadData` on a table view instance, does it make all `UITableViewDataSource` calls async?
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you see [How to tell when UITableView has completed ReloadData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This method actually just removes all the `UITableViewCell` views from the table. The data source delegate methods are called when the table is repainted.

So, it's asynchronous.

Edit:

Actually, some calls ARE synchronous. The number of sections & rows and row heights are updated immediately, so, for example `contentSize` is set correctly after the call. On the other hand, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:` is not called until the table is repainted.

Comment: so if i had an array backing the tableview. cellForRowAtIndexPath would crash if the array is updated before it gets called, how should we fix this?

Comment: @bogardon I don't understand - why would it crash?

Comment: It crashes if reloadData is called again before all the `cellForRow...` calls are made and the new number of cells < old number of cells. `cellForRow` asks for too high of an index

Comment: At least in the case of collection views on iOS 8.2+, numberOfItemsInSection is also called asynchronously, driven from the layout code (flow layout etc).

Comment: @bendytree so do I have to prevent such situation?

Comment: You don't have to. When you reload the data, it will check number of sections and items per section before calling cellForRowAt. So if you call reloadData after updating your array it'll work as expected. However, if you silently change your array and not call reloadData, it will crash.